# How to escape operators like >, < in jsrender json name references?

Tags: jsrender

**Problem**

Template compilation fails:

```
'<tr><td>No Heartbeat {{:name}} : {{:Heartbeat>30d}}</td></tr>'
```

See JS Fiddle : [Issue Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h65KX/10/)

**JSON Source**

```
{ "name": "Desktops", "Heartbeat>30d": 3004 }
```

**Wanted**

Escaping the JSRender Expression: {{:Heartbeat>30d}} to reference the JSON Field and compile properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#data["name of the property"]` to access some properties. So, your template should look like this:

```
'<tr><td>No Heartbeat {{:name}} : {{:#data["Heartbeat>30d"]}}</td></tr>'
```

I have updated jsfiddle example you provided:

http://jsfiddle.net/h65KX/11/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Did you forget a ] ?  just after the close quote?